# React test, count number of updates after dispatch action

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, sinon

Using jest or sinon or enzyme how I can count number of updates of my component after dispatching an action?

Comment: it would be rather antipattern to check that in unit test. what is the reason you need that?

Comment: I want to prevent unnecessary updates after dispatch an action.

Answer (score 0):

do n't know in jest or enzyme, but u can see no of updates/commits using react profiler tool provided by facebook (https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html)

Answer (score 0):

With Jest. you can count total times the function was called by using the similar code below.

**Mock function**

```
const mockCallback = jest.fn(() => ({}));
```

**Verify**

```
expect(mockCallback.mock.calls.length).toBe(2);
```

Comment: thanks, but  I used redux in my component, How can i use mock function with dispatch? so that after dispatch actoin I can measure number of calls?